# Waiting for a response from AlertDialog or Theme.Dialog Activity with onBackPressed()

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have looked at quite a few posts on here and haven't been able to get anything to work. I am trying to have either an AlertDialog or an Activity class (set to a Theme.Dialog style) prompt users to see if they want to exit a side Activity and go back to the Home activity. Everything I have tried just doesn't seem to work.

[NOTE: All of the following examples were tried as the first lines in...]

```
@Override public void onBackPressed(){}
```

I have tried -

```
Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(setIntent);
```

which closes both the current Activity and the Home menu Activity (the next Activity in the stack), while -

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { 
                        Session.closing = true;
                    }
                })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Session.closing = false;
                    }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

closes the current Activity and creates a pop-up over the Home activity. This is the outcome of most of the other things I have tried, like...

```
super.onBackPressed();
startActivity(new Intent(this, CloseActivityView.class));
```

Are there any tricks to getting onBackPressed from dumping your current child Activity?

Comment: what i understood is, you want an Alert if user, while on HomeScreen, presses back button, and if user presses yes, then application should exit, is that so ?

Comment: Close, similar idea anyway. I want an alert if the user presses the back button to go from a secondary activity back to the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't call `super.onBackPressed();` - this will call `finish()` and your current activity will be removed.

Secondly, this:

```
Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
```

creates an intent that **launches the Home screen**. (See the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) docs)

What you could do is put something like this in your `onBackPressed` override:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { 
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            })
        .setNegativeButton("No", null); // I think passing null here is OK.
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Then specify your `HomeActivity` as `launchMode="singleTask"` in your manifest, as detailed in the [Tasks and Back Stack docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks). You could do the same thing by specifying the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag on the Intent for navigating to your HomeActivity.

Comment: Let me take a look at this. I remember having to use singleTask in one of my other small apps now, but I can't remember what it's functionality was at the time. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a confirmation dialog on back button press then override the `onBackPressed` and show the `AlertDialog`. If user confirms then call `dialog.dismiss()` to dismiss the dialog and then if you want to exit the app and go to the home screen then finish this activity and start the homescreen intent and the code you have tried for this is right. or if you want to go back to an activity within your app then you can start that activity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. Don't call `super.onBackPressed()` in your overriden version unless you want to finish the current Activity.

Comment: I will take a look at this as well. I feel like I have done the dialog.dismiss() on confirmation thing and it still finishes my current activity early.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Three things to say:

1. if your home activity contents are not changed after navigating away from it, and doing some operations, then, i recommend that when you are navigating awway from homw screen, don't call `finish()`. Let the home screen be in the activity stack. So when the child activity has to navigate back to home activity, it just needs to finish its own activity, and Home screen will appear after that.
2. Your code is somewhat perfect. All you have to do is finish the activity when `yes` button is pressed on `AlertDialog`
3. And on Homescreen, inside onBackPressed() or whatever you prefer, just show the AlertDialog (that you have shown above), and you can code for `Yes` and `No` buttons